# Вывод страниц из БД в Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, конструкцию вывод страниц из базы данных в Laravel.
Например, site.ru/hello-world

Comment: "обращение -> запрос к БД -> вывод", не благодарите...

Answer (score 4):

В первую очередь, необходимо настроить подключение к вашей базе данных. Для этого в Laravel >= 5 есть конфигурационный файл `.env` *(находится в корне проекта)*

После настройки нужно создать файл миграций, следуя соглашению. К примеру, вам нужна таблица "магазин" - значит называть её нужно во множественном числе *(магазины - прим. перевод: **shops**)*. Для этого открываете вашу консоль, переходите *(с помощью команды **cd**)* в директорию, в которой установлен фреймворк, и выполняете команду:

```
php artisan make:migration create_shops_table
```

Эта команда создаст файл примерно с таким именем:

```
ваш.сайт\database\migrations\2018_03_12_175226_create_shops_table.php
```

Открываете этот файл в вашей среде разработки, и записываете в метод `up()` названия полей. Для примера, можете просто скопировать этот код - для запуска и демонстрации этого будет достаточно:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateShopsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('text');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('shops');
    }
}
```

После сохранения изменений в файле миграций, нужно выполнить в консоли следующую команду *(запустить миграции)*:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Эта команда создаст в базе данных таблицу `shops` с несколькими полями.

Далее, нужно создать модель `Shop`. Для этого выполняете в консоли команду:

```
php artisan make:model Shop
```

После создания модели *(на данном этапе её не нужно редактировать)* запускаете в консоли удобный инструмент для работы с базой данных Тинкер, он понадобится для записи в базу наших значений, которые позже мы выведем в браузер:

```
php artisan tinker
```

В открывшемся интерфейсе пишете следующий код *(в конце каждого выражения нажимаете "Ввод")*

Создаёте экземпляр класса Shop:

```
$shop = new App\Shop;
```

Сохраняете тестовый текст в свойстве `text` экземпляра класса Shop:

```
$shop->text = 'Текст для записи в базу (Hello, World! - или что вам было нужно...)';
```

Выполняете запись в базу с помощью метода `save()` *(если запись успешна, после нажатия на "Ввод" вы увидите **true**)*:

```
$shop->save();
```

После этого интерфейс Тинкера нужно закрыть командой `exit` - при этом вы увидите сообщение `Exit:  Goodbye.`

Далее в файле `ваш.сайт\routes\web.php` нужно создать маршрут, по которому фреймворк будет вызывать необходимый контроллер. Для примера, назовём контроллер `Hello`, тогда наш маршрут будет выглядеть так:

```
Route::get('hello-world', 'HelloController@index');
```

Далее в консоли создаём контроллер с помощью команды

```
php artisan make:controller HelloController
```

Контроллер будет создан по адресу: `ваш.сайт\app\Http\Controllers\HelloController.php`
Открываем его в IDE для редактирования, и вставляем в него этот код:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Shop;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $shops = Shop::all();
        return view('hello', compact('shops'));
    }
}
```

После сохранения изменений останется создать файл-шаблон `hello.blade.php` в директории `ваш.сайт\resources\views\`, и прописать в нём этот код:

```
@foreach ($shops as $shop)
    <div class="body">{{ $shop->text }}</div>
@endforeach
```

---

Всё, что вам останется сделать, это запустить ваш маршрут по адресу: `http://ваш.сайт/hello-world`

Если всё сделано правильно, в браузере вы увидите текст: `Текст для записи в базу (Hello, World! - или что вам было нужно...)`